# Multithreading/scheduling on a single core MCU

Tags: c, multithreading, embedded, scheduling, sensors

Currently, I'm using an MCU to record sensor data. The sensor have a 96 FIFO and a sampling rate at 4kHz. That means it flows over in 96/4000 seconds or 24ms. The RAM on the unit is 256kB and the data rate from the sensor is 32kB/s. Saving 20 seconds of data thus overflows the RAM and I need to write the data to memory continuously during a triggering event.

I have been using an SD-card for this. However, it draws too much current to always be mounted, requiring me to mount it at an event and dismount it once the event is over. The mounting process, however, takes 100-400 ms, that is, way too long and data is lost.

And so I've been thinking of multithreading the processes such that:

We run the sd-card-mounting thread while the FIFO buffer is below a certain value. Either by polling the sensor and asking for a count of FIFO entries or by using a timer(if you can do it down to msec in a proper way)

If the FIFO buffer is above that value, we pause the mounting thread and save FIFO entries to RAM. Once the queue is close to 0, we switch back to mount thread.

After mounting thread is done, we write blocks of data from RAM to sd-card using the same logic of thread switching as above.

Is this feasible or a completely incorrect design choice? Maybe it can't be done. If so, do you have any idea or alternative to solve this problem?

Comment: Multitthreading on a single core sounds like ... scheduling.

Comment: I'll add that term for clarity

Comment: @wildplasser it is multithreading.

Comment: Is the hardware design open for change? I'd be asking for an MCU with more RAM. If you're lucky, maybe there's one from the same vendor with the same pinout, and the hardware team would only need to change the BOM. If they can't do that for you, then what if they added a SPI-attached, external, byte-wide SRAM chip (or two)? (e.g., https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/microchip-technology/23LC1024-I-SN/3543084)

Comment: What is the write speed of the SD card (with FS overhead)? You can save 4 seconds of data into 128KB of ram. But, seriously, get an MCU with more power and ram--it's 2022 not 1985. Do you have ethernet/MII?  Or a uart and what speed does it have? Or add sram as Solomon suggests. What is SD card unmount time?

Comment: P.S., You say the sensor captures 4k samples per second. But, what does it sense? Do you _need_ 4k samples per second? or is that just how the sensor works? Have you looked at FFTs of the signal? How are the data going to be used? What are the highest frequencies that you care about? Are you sure you can't down-sample it on the fly and store less data?

Comment: 'run the sd-card-mounting thread while the fifobuffer is below a certain value. Either by polling the sensor and asking for a count of fifo entries or by using a timer' does the sampling thread that loads data into the buffers not know how much space is left?  When a buffer-load reduces the space below some 'low water mark', it could signal the 'mount-write-dismount' thread to save the accumulated data and free up space before the buffer/s get completely full, no?  I don't see why you need to poll or use some timer.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But let's say i sample 100 entries before switching to mount thread, how do I switch from the mount thread to sample thread? If I mount it all at once, data is lost!

Comment: @SolomonSlow No, I can't upgrade the RAM but I have been thinking of an intermediate SRAM buffer like you propose. That could be one solution. We need 4k sps, it is important to keep up that sps and not lose data points.

Comment: @CraigEstey the design choice is due to power consumption, this will be a battery operated unit and as such, not any MCU will do. Data is sent over LTE. The unmount time is the same as the mount time, between 100-400 ms.

Answer (score 0):

You have plenty of RAM. Simply define buffer in the RAM. Save to this buffer. When the buffer is half full save the first half to SD card, then the second.

Use RTOS for that and use interrupts to read from MPU and you will be fine.

Comment: Yes, that is the idea but the mounting process is too slow. I cant write to the sd-card until that has completet. So, the device is always active, listening for a triggering event. The trigger happens -> mount sd-card -> start saving data. The mounting part takes too long and I can't lose datapoints after triggerevent.

Comment: Normally you'd rather have multiple buffers of the same size, one "work buffer" and one "being copied buffer", then swap pointers between them. Then you only need to protect the pointer swaps from race conditions, not the buffers themselves.

Comment: Sure but that doesn't solve the timing problem

Comment: @Lundin many hardware devices have half buffer DMA interrupts in the circular modes. It is perfect application for DMA